# Saving and Retrieving Spinner position with SQL

Tags: android, database, android-spinner

So i have a working SQL db that utilizes VARCHARs for all its values. I have no problem with this and use it for multiple apps.

I have realized that for many of the parts of my app a spinner would be better than having the user actually input text on their own since it would be quicker, prettier, etc.

Here is my problem. I cannot seem to save the position of the spinner, and have no idea then how to retrieve it if i can figure it out. I have minimized my code to only focus on getting this to work with one spinner having the db only save two values. A text view and the spinner.

here is my code (It should be noted that i am trying everything i can think of. Defining the variables as long, int, object.... etc etc so there may be some code discrepancies )

Db opener code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key     autoincrement,name VARCHAR, save long);";                 
    db.execSQL(createQuery);        
}
```

DB Connector code

```
 public void insertContact( String name, long choice) 
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("name", name);
              newCon.put("save", choice);
               open();
              database.insert("country", null, newCon);
              close();
           }


           public void updateContact(long id, String name, long choice) 
           {
              ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
              editCon.put("name",name);
              editCon.put("save", choice);

              open();
              database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }
```

ADD/Edit activity class

```
 setContentView(R.layout.add_country);
      spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);
      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
      spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      spin.setAdapter(adapter);
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));

         spin.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<?>)spin.getAdapter()).getPosition(null));           }
  private void saveContact() 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact
          (nameEt.getText().toString(),
           spin.getItemIdAtPosition(choice));
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            spin.getItemIdAtPosition(choice));


      }
   }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3){
 saved = spin.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
 int choice = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

View Class

```
public class ViewCountry extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;

   TextView ep;




   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);
      Button a = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editbuttons);
       Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deletebuttons);
      a.setOnClickListener(this);
      b.setOnClickListener(this);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);

       ep = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.newText99);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");

         int epicIndex = result.getColumnIndex("save");


         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));

         ep.setText(result.getString(epicIndex));


         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }


   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());

            addEditContact.putExtra("save", ep.getText());

            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }
   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }
```

Sorry if i'm missing data to give you. I cut out a bunch from the first three sections of code to minimize reading time. Let me know if you need something else. I've tried everything i can think of.

This is after adjustment to the code

DB Opener

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key     autoincrement,name VARCHAR, save int);";                 
        db.execSQL(createQuery);
```

DB Connector Class

```
  public void insertContact( String name, int choice) 
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("name", name);
              newCon.put("save", choice);
               open();
              database.insert("country", null, newCon);
              close();
           }


           public void updateContact(long id, String name, int choice) 
           {
              ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
              editCon.put("name",name);
              editCon.put("save", choice);

              open();
              database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }
```

Add/Edit Class

I'm having trouble figuring out where to insert the new bundle and code.

This is what i've done

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
      Bundle contact = dbConnector.updateContact(saved);
```

Here i get the error "The method updateContact (Long, String, int) in the type dbConnector is not applicable for the arguments (String)"
          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));
             spin.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)spin.getAdapter()).getPosition(null));}
          String name  = contact.getString("name");
             int position = contact.getInt("position");
             spin.setSelection(position);

Now here, later in the same activity i get a similar error

```
       private void saveContact() 
   {


      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact
          (nameEt.getText().toString(),
           spin.getItemIdAtPosition(choice));
```

here it says "The method insertContact (String, int) in the type dbconnector is not applicable to the arguments (String, long)"

where its getting the long from i dont know since i've removed it everywhere i thought. 
          }
          else
          {
             dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                nameEt.getText().toString(),
                spin.getItemIdAtPosition(choice));

here it errors out with "The method insertContact (long, String, int) in the type dbconnector is not applicable to the arguments (long String, long)"

```
      }
   }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3){
 saved = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Those are at the moment the only errors i have. I feel like i'm on the edge but cant figure out where the last problem really is.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work.. what exactly does that mean? Also, there is no "long" data type in SQLite when you create your table. use INTEGER. You can still retrieve it using getLong and save it by passing a long into your ContentValues

Comment: It not only does not seem to save the position but then i do not know the way to return it.

Comment: When i change the code to all int instead of long it give me the error "The method insertContact in the type databaseConnector is not applicable for the following arguments (Long, string, int)" then it tells me to change it back to a long

Comment: I think dymmeh meant change long to integer in your SQL table declaration, not in your contact methods.

Answer (score 0):

A few things....

**1:**

In your `saveContact()` method, you have the following code:

`spin.getItemIdAtPosition(choice));`

However the `choice` variable you reference is both declared and instantiated inside of the `onItemSelected` method.  Once that finishes running, `choice` won't be available for you to use.  Instead, declare it as a class variable above as you did your `spin` and `nameEt` variables and populate it in `onItemSelected`.  Then you can reference it:

`spin.getItemIdAtPosition(this.choice));`

**2:**

Your `insertContact` and `updateContact` methods both expect the position to be a long.  You are sending them with the `Spinner` method getItemIdAtPosition(), which will return an int!

**3:**

You aren't updating the spinner from the database anywhere!  You'll have to query the database for the name and position.  Then use the Spinner method `setSelection(int position)`:

```
// I'm assuming a method in your dbConnecter called "getContact" that returns 
// a Bundle which contains a name and position.  I'm also assuming you have the
// id of the contact you want.  I'm calling it "contactId".

    Bundle contact = dbConnector.getContact(contactId);

    String name  = contact.getString("name");
    int position = contact.getInt("position");

    nameEt.setText(name);
    spin.setSelection(position)
```

Comment: Added adjusted code to the end of the OP Thanks for the help man

Comment: @TheRedStig Just looking through previous answers I posted.  Did this work for you?